# CSS: how to center a text with a font icon?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have built a round div. I want to realize that the number text can horizontally center in the div, and the font icon locates in its top right corner, how to realize that? 
The div definition is :

```css
   .rating-score {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: #ff6666;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .question-mark {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rating-score">
    8.9<span class="fa fa-question-circle question-mark"></span>
</div>
```

I have build a jsfiddle here:
    [round div with text and font icon](https://jsfiddle.net/zwoz6az7/#)

Comment: By font icon, do you mean the question-mark?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zwoz6az7/2/

Comment: I forget to notice one thing, I must keep .rating-score `position:absolute` property, I need to put it on top of a image.

Answer (score 0):

Give `position: relative;` to `.rating-score` and `position: absolute;` to `.question-mark` and adjust `top` and `left` will give your expected output.

```
.question-mark {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top:1px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwoz6az7/1/)**

Comment: I forget to notice one thing, I must keep .rating-score `position:absolute` property, I need to put it on top of a image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can change `.rating-score` `position:absolute` to `position:relative` but it should work also if you do not change it.

```
.question-mark {
  font-size: 12px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon need to be absolute positioned and the parent positioned relatively like so

```css
.rating-score {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #ff6666;
    color: #fff;
}

.question-mark {
   font-size: 12px!important;
   position: absolute;
   top: 8px;
   right: 9px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rating-score">
    8.9<span class="fa fa-question-circle question-mark"></span>
</div>
```